# Python/Tkinter ¿Es posible rotar imágenes .jpg o .png y texto en un canvas en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

¿Es posible cargar una imagen en un canvas y rotarla por ejemplo 45° cada vez que se hace clic derecho sobre dicha imagen? ¿O es necesario utilizar pygame para lograrlo?

Todos los ejemplos de rotación que encuentro son solamente para polígonos dibujados en el canvas, pero no para imágenes ni texto.
¿O es posible hacer clic en una esquina de la imagen o texto y rotarlos arbitrariamente moviendo el puntero del ratón?

Algunos explican que al hacerlo se pierde información de la imagen y se van presentando errores, que sería mejor ir guardando cada cambio en la caché. ¿Cómo se hace eso? Y cuánto afectaría esto al rendimiento del programa. Si es una imagen muy grande afectaría al rendimiento de la máquina?

Answer (score 1):

En Python existe una librería llamada [PILLOW](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) (que se referencia como PIL) es una de las más simples para tratamiento de imágenes. Existe una rutina simple para hacer lo que necesitas:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
im.rotate(45).show()
```

[Puedes ver más referencias aquí:](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html) y en [The Python Imaging Library Handbook](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/)

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por la rutina. No funciona para girar la imagen y verla en el mismo canvas. Al parecer sólo gira la imagen, la guarda y la abre en el programa predeterminado para ver dicho tipo de imágenes (.jpg) como Paint o así por el estilo. Pero para girar una imagen y ver inmediatamente su resultado en canvas no funciona.